# Flutter: Login/http request

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I'm trying to do a login screen, using the textformfields for username and password, in which, when I press the login button, it does an http request to a server trying retrieve user data and, if it's all good, it navigates to a second screen, but, if not, it displays the error. I have a problem to show this error, I don't know how to do it! I'll put what I've done so far:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
      right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10),
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.person),
                  hintText: "Insert username",
                ),
                onSaved: (val) => username = val,
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? "Insert username" : null,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
              new TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.lock),
                  hintText: "Insert password",
                ),
                onSaved: (val) => password = val,
                validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? "insert password" : null,
              ),
            ],
          )),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      ),
      new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
            right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => validate(),
          child: Text("Login",
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              )),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
));}
  validate()async {

final FormState form = _formKey.currentState;

if (form.validate()){
  form.save();
  form.reset();



  var user = await login(username, password);
  if (user != null){

    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/secondPage', ModalRoute.withName('/secondPage'));

  }

}}
```

Comment: On else case, you can show alert box.. will that works for you?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't enter in the else case :/

Comment: login Method should return `User` and if it is `null` showAlertMessage. Its better to not to move showAlert inside `login` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way:

```
final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
if (result .statusCode == 200) {
 Fluttertoast.showToast(
 msg: "Login success! Welcome, " + result["username"],
 toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
 gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
 timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
 backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
 textColor: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 16.0);
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
prefs.setString("userId", result["id"].toString());

String url = "someUrl";
http.Response userData = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final userDataResult = json.decode(userData.body);
prefs.setString("first_name", userDataResult["first_name"].toString());
prefs.setString("last_name", userDataResult["last_name"].toString());
prefs.setString("role", userDataResult["role"].toString());
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/main");
}
else{
Fluttertoast.showToast(
 msg: "Credential is not recognized",
 toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
 gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
 timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
 backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
 textColor: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 16.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I find a way, probably. In the login function, I write:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200){
 return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
}else{
 return showAlertMessage(context, response.statusCode.toString());
```

}

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

p.s. under `return showAlertMessage(context, response.statusCode.toString());` should I also write a `throw Exception()`?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, the best way would be returning the HTTP response itself (in login function). then in the widget decide what to do according to status code and if the status code is 4xx there is an error and show the error. you can define the error based on the status code or the response.body.

or the other way is to just throw an exception and handle the error in the catch block.